# I can't find the number data with SQL Server like

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

The data is registered in the database with the number 5056381825. But when I like this number with 905056381825, a blank result is returned. What's the solution?

Comment: can you please provide some more information.  We need the table definition, and for you to tell us which field has the number pattern you re searching for.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. Table  : prCurrAccCommunication Column : CommAddress Type : nvarchar(100)

Comment: so that 12 digit number is a CommAddress?

Comment: You have changed the code in your question. I get the impression that this edit invalidates the existing answers. This is not appreciated. Please consider undoing that edit and asking a new question on the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

The `LIKE` seems to be in the wrong direction.  Try:

```
where '905056381825' LIKE CONCAT('%', number, '%')
```

It is not clear from your question what the name of the column is in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the correct query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM prCurrAccCommunication
WHERE CommAddress LIKE CONCAT('%', number, '%')
```

Comment: The blank result has returned.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how the data is stored?